# Use omniauth-facebook when app id and app secret are different for each request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

The [omniauth-facebook](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook) README mentions how to set it up in an initializer and how to set options like `scope` per request only. I wonder if it is possible to set app id and app secret per request as well.

Comment: I'm wondering why would you want to set app id and app secret per request. There is only one key per app.

Comment: What if my site needs to support more than one facebook apps? Think SaaS.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do this:

On your omniauth.rb, do this:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook,:setup => true
end
```

Then on your controller you have to define the following:

```
def setup
 request.env['omniauth.strategy'].options[:client_id] = @site.facebook_key
 request.env['omniauth.strategy'].options[:client_secret] = @site.facebook_secret
 render :text => "Setup complete.", :status => 404
end
```

Of course you have to add the associated routes, on your routes.rb.

```
  #Facebook Omniauth routes
  match '/auth/facebook/callback' => 'session#authorize_callback'
  match '/auth/facebook/setup' => 'session#setup'
```

Good luck

Regards.
Ivan.

Comment: So it makes one more request to '/auth/facebook/setup' for each authentication process? And why that `:status => 404`?

Comment: And how to config `OmniAuth.config.full_host`?

Comment: I got this to work, but not with Twitter as well... I set up two `setup` methods, but it seems omniauth-twitter doesn't have this same functionality?

Comment: Kyle, I'm not sure if this helps but, in the case of twitter you have to replace the  "request.env['omniauth.strategy'].options[:client_id]" to "request.env['omniauth.strategy'].options[:consumer_key]" and the "request.env['omniauth.strategy'].options[:client_secret]" to "request.env['omniauth.strategy'].options[:consumer_secret]".

Answer (score 5):

I use devise (followed this railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-devise-and-omniauth-revised), but it took me a while to understand how to implement Ivangrx' solution. It turned out to be quite easy. Here's my code:

```
# /config/initializers/devise.rb
config.omniauth :facebook, setup: true

# routes.rb
devise_scope :user do  
  #where omniauth_callback is the controller I made when following the Railscast
  get "users/auth/facebook/setup" => "omniauth_callbacks#setup"
end

# omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb
def setup
  request.env['omniauth.strategy'].options[:client_id] = @site.facebook_id
  request.env['omniauth.strategy'].options[:client_secret] = @site.facebook_key
  render :text => "Setup complete.", :status => 404
end
```

Thanks for the help on this one!

Comment: Is it possible to use the same setup function to handle multiple strategies (for example: both `facebook` and `google_oauth2`).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using devise you can do this

```
config.omniauth  :facebook, :setup => lambda{
      current_app_secret = // Get current domain
      current_app_key = // Get config
      env['omniauth.strategy'].options[:client_id] = current_app_secret
      env['omniauth.strategy'].options[:client_secret] = current_app_key
    }
```

Comment: Where to this code? An initializer? What if `current_app_secret` needs to be fetched from database? It looks ugly to have ActiveRecord code in an initializer even if it works.

Comment: I think you should be able to override them in application controller also. You can write a before_filter in application_controller. Let me know what happens.

Comment: Thanks! But actually I am not using devise. My site does not need any feature provided by devise.

Comment: It doesn't work for me: /users/auth/facebook redirects me and I get `No route matches [GET] "/oauth/authorize"`