# Set different facebook oauth scope per user with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, devise, omniauth

I have a rails app with two separate types of users (call them A and B).  Right now they can both sign in with facebook.  However, I need B to be able to oauth with some extended permissions, and I DO NOT want A to give me the extended permissions.

Inside config/initializers/devise.rb

```
config.omniauth :facebook, "API_KEY", "API_SECRET", :client_options => {:ssl => {:ca_path => '  /path/to/my/ssl/stuff'}}
```

I know I can add

```
:scope => "extended_permissions"
```

But I only want the extended permissions to happen when B users sign up.

Since this is in an initializer is this even possible?  Or can I somehow config.omniauth elsewhere in the app and keep devise happy?

Comment: You can take a look to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13524919/use-omniauth-facebook-when-app-id-and-app-secret-are-different-for-each-request/13528277#13528277 and set dynamically the app id, the app secret and the options per request

Comment: Check the gem's [github](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook#per-request-options).

Answer (score 1):

It's clearly explained in the documentation

> If you want to set the display format, auth_type, or scope on a
>   per-request basis, you can just pass it to the OmniAuth request phase
>   URL, for example: /auth/facebook?display=popup or
>   /auth/facebook?scope=email.

source: https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook#per-request-options